# How to access subcollections from Firestore in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a collection and a subcollection, with the collection's name being a variable that the user inputs. I don't know the code to actually call the subcollection when the collection is a variable.

I've done it before in Dart, and essentially used:
`return db.collection('$company/users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({...`
but js appears to just read it as a string.
I've tried several variations:

```
return db.collection('${company}/users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({...
return db.collection(company'/users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({...
return db.collection(company + '/users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({...
return db.collection(company, '/users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({...
return db.collection(company).collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({...
```

Expected results: Collection and Subcollection area created, with the collection taking in the company String and the subcollection being users.
The exact code works with a single collection, whether I try "users" or the variable company, but I don't know how to get them to work together.

Actual results: No collection made, error of "Invalid Collection Reference"
(slightly different errors depending on what I tried).

Comment: have you checked https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections ?

Comment: No, now it works perfectly. I for some reason had forgotten the doc in between collections. Thanks Vadym.